# Pass script tag value to input tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass a particular variable value from the script tag to an input tag. But somehow it is not working.

I am trying to pass `variable1` value from the below code from script tag to input tag.

So suppose `variable1` value is `John` then this line in my code will look like this-

```
<input ONCLICK="window.location.href='some_url&textId=John'">
```

Below is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applying</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function getUrlVars() {

    // some code

}
var variable1 = getUrlVars()["parameter1"];
var variable1 = unescape(variable1);

// some more code

</script>

<input ONCLICK="window.location.href='some_url&textId=variable1'">

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain me what wrong I am doing?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: I am trying to pass variable1 value to input tag at the end.

Comment: You want it to appear in the input field when it is clicked?

Comment: at onclick call a function, inside that function set window.locatio.href !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it that way:

```
var variable1 = getUrlVars()["parameter1"];
variable1 = unescape(variable1);
document.getElementById('Apply').onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = 'some_url&textID=' + variable1;
};
```

That attaches a function to the onclick event that exactly does what you want. For the initial input element simply remove the onclick attribute:

```
<input name="Apply" type="button" id="Apply" value="Apply" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to the following if your trying to bind the click handler to this input element:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Applying</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function getUrlVars() {

    // some code

}
var variable1 = getUrlVars()["parameter1"];
var variable1 = unescape(variable1);

document.getElementById("Apply").onclick = function() {
    window.location.href='some_url&textId=' + variable1;
}

// some more code

</script>

<input name="Apply" type="button" id="Apply" value="Apply" >

</body>
</html>
```

I haven't tested it yet but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to perform inline functions, you need to wrap the code in an executable closure:

```
<input name="Apply" type="button" id="Apply" value="Apply" ONCLICK="(function() {window.location.href='your_data'})();">
```

As this can be largely unmaintainable, I recommend you abstract this functionality into a more organized place in your application.

```
(function(window, $, undefined) {
  // assuming you use jQuery
  $('#Apply').click(function() {
   window.location.href = '';// your code
  })
})(window, $);
```

I may be totally misunderstanding what you want to do, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The whole url parameters bit is surely unnecessary.

You can just set the value attribute in the field:

```
var field = document.getElementById('textfield');
var value = 'Some text';

field.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.setAttribute('value', value);
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/LMpb2/

Answer (score 0):

You have it inside the ' '  you need to add it into the string. So try

```
         "window.location.href='some_url&textId='+variable1+';'"
```

Answer (score 0):

at onclick call a function, inside that function set window.locatio.href !

a sample

```
<script>
var url="www.google.com";
function myfunc(){
alert(url);
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="myfunc()" value="btn" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CgKHN/